# Is RDP secure enough? China/HK Access

Tags: windows, firewalls, vpn, rdp

I have offices in China and HK and for local internet all fine. International connectivity is very slow indeed - not usable. They need to access a terminal server in the UK and do this by using SSLVPN to the UK. From HK it is very slow and China not usable.

So one solution is to buy in some international bandwidth (not cheap) or use a hosted server at a datacentre. The idea would be that they RDP to the server in the datacentre and then off that server use SSLVPN to the UK to use the application on the terminal server. I have tried it and it works ok.

My concern is the connection from the machine to the datacentre server only using RDP. I am either restricted by the great firewall of China or the hosting company.

Any thoughts if this is secure enough? I have changed the RDP port and also secured it down to certain IP's.

Comment: Why not put the application directly on the hosted server then? And if communication with the hosted server works then why not use it as a VPN gateway, and then connect to your UK server through it?

Answer (score 0):

By default, RDP connections are encrypted using the [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4) stream cipher, which is not considered secure anymore.

If possible you should [tunnel your RDP session through TLS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff458357.aspx) or set up an encrypted VPN between your RDP server and your workstation.

Comment: but the issue here is the china firewall blocking everything.

Comment: Many hosting companies are saying that remote desktop is secure enough but I had my doubts but I am a bit stuck as on one side I ahve the hosting company and the other side the china firewall blocking everything.  Can you encrypt everything using an ssl cert if I could get it installed on the server ?